# How to skip lines in matlab when doing for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a variable `A` which is dimension of 1X100. I want to assign `A(i)=i`. However, starting from m=20, I need to assign 1 to the next 20 arraies.

```
A=zeros(1,100);
for m=1:100
    A(m)=m; disp(m);
    if m==20
        A(m:m+20)=1;
        m=m+21;
    end
end
```

When I run it, the output display m=1 to 100, which means that it does not skip from m=20 to m=40. Is it possible to write a command to skip the 20 iterations in the for loop? I know I can try to use other ways like while loop or assigning A(20:40)=1 provided that A has the value in each cell. But I would like to emphasize the use of for loop here. This is the only restriction.

Comment: In MATLAB it is _always_ recommended to use matrix and vector operations instead of loops. Where the heck does this restriction come from?

Answer (score 2):

Matlab does not allow modifying the value of the iteration variable (here `m`) inside the loop.

You can either to as @NickMattson suggests, and maybe simplify it a bit like this:

```
A=ones(1,100);
for m=[1:20, 41:100]
    A(m)=m; disp(m);
end
```

or use the [continue](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html) keyword inside the loop:

```
A=ones(1,100);
for m=1:100
    if m >= 20 && m <= 40
        continue
    end
    A(m)=m; disp(m);
end
```

or use a `while loop`:

```
A=zeros(1,100);
m = 1;
while m <= 100
    if m == 20 
       m = 41
    end
    A(m)=m; disp(m);
    m = m + 1
end
```

But of course the easiest would be:

```
A = 1:100;
A(20:40)=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your `m` in that way

```
A=zeros(1,100);
for m=[1:20, 41:100]
    A(m)=m; disp(m);
    if m==20
        A(m:m+20)=1;
    end
end
```